# HTML Forms: Display entered data on a separate page

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple HTML form like this:

```
<form name='input' action='thankyou.jsp' method='post'>
<p>Email Address: <input type='text' name='email' size='16' /><br>
<p>Password: <input type='password' name='password' size='16' /><br>
<p>Verify Password: <input type='password' name='verifypassword' size='16' /><br>
<br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit your data'/>
</form>
```

I want to be able to take the information a user enters and display it on a thank you page afterwards, how could I go about doing so?

Comment: Do you know any server-side scripting languages?

Comment: Not really, If you can point me to some tutorials, I can probably begin to pick it up, I just literally need to do this for a mini-project at the start of my apprenticeship

Comment: Google helps for tutorials. StackOverflow isn't really the best place to ask for tutorials. PHP's probably your best bet, and I learned just by reading the manual @ http://php.net/

Comment: I'm currently setup in a development enviroment, as I'm in an office enviroment, using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat, I'm not sure how easily I can implement PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first study the `server-side scripting language`,if you want to read JavaScript than this link may help you.
visit this site [Click Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

you can also choose other scripting language which you understand easily.